# Eclipse error - Java was started but returned exit code = 13 is still happening after multiple changes

Tags: java, eclipse

Since some weeks back my Eclipse has stopped working and I can see that it's caused by some Java conflict. I have tried a lot of stuff seen online but nothing works. So now I ask the question here.

**But first let me give you some information:**

[Java version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj2us.png) Which tells i am on 64 bit.

[eclipse.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqals.png) My eclipse.ini file tell me that I am on 64 bit Eclipse

[System 64 bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1qbM.png) My system is running 64 bit as well. So all three is having 64 bit which is a great then.

---

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oeuv.png) Here is the error I get when opening Eclipse.

As you can see in the error message I've already tried to add the -vm statement to my javaw location in eclipse.ini and that didn't do it.

Also, I tried to do changes [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDyYY.png) in the environment variables. I removed the path for 'javapath' but that didnt work either. I also tried to add the path for 'javaw' but no luck there either.

**Do you have any idea on how to further troubleshoot and/or solve this?**

Thanks.

Comment: It says `-arch x86` in that image - that is 32 bit, the eclipse.ini also says x86 - 32 bit. it would be x86_64 for 64 bit.

Comment: "My eclipse.ini file tell me that I am on 64 bit Eclipse"—Where does it say that?

Comment: I was looking at the wrong installation when saying it was '64 bit'. In the screenshot I can see it's 32 bit. Sorry for the confusion. So maybe I'll try to install a 32-bit Java then?

Comment: _So maybe I'll try to install a 32-bit Java then?_ No, just install 64 bit Eclipse from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: Install the current version of Java that has Java embedded to run itself (and yes, coding in older Java versions is still supported). The `v2011...` in the `eclipse.ini` means 2011, so you about one decade behind.